# How to fix laravel 8 UI paginate problem?

Tags: php, laravel, user-interface, pagination, laravel-8

I had a problem while trying out the recently released laravel 8, I'm trying to find out what the changes are and how it works. When I did that I had a problem with the paginate laravel 8 UI getting messy and somehow it happened. Is there anyone who can help me? or have experienced the same thing?

Like this the view I got in laravel 8
[Laravel 8 paginate UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzWYl.png)

and this is the code I use "Index.blade.php"

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Post')

@section('contents')

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            @foreach ($posts as $post)
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="card mb-4">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                {{ $post->title }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                {{ $post->body }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer">
                                {{ $post->created_at->diffForHumans() }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
        <div class="d-felx justify-content-center">

            {{ $posts->links() }}

        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

the code I use for PostController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Posts;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Posts::latest()->paginate(6);
        // dd($post);
        return view('post.index', compact('posts'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using tailwind or bootstrap?

Comment: Have you noticed this [Upgrade Guide point](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#pagination-defaults) ?

Answer (score 123):

just make sure you have this in your AppServiceProvider.

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

public function boot()
{
     Paginator::useBootstrap();
}
```

and you're good to go.

Comment: wow . you saved my huge time. thanks

Comment: this is exact answer I was searching

Comment: Manoj ji, shukriya n ji. ਤੁਸੀਂ ਅਦਭੁਤ ਕੀਤਾ., sat sri akal ji

Comment: this answer doesn't have enough votes

Answer (score 69):

I tried doing adding the `Paginator::useBootstrap();` in the `AppServiceProvider.php` but it didn't work.

But this worked:

```
// Directly in your blade file
$posts->links('pagination::bootstrap-4')
```

Comment: It worked for me.
But I used Bootstrap 5 version on this Laravel project. 
So, pagination looks funny.
http://prntscr.com/1q9hnu8

Is there any way to use Bootstrap 5?

Comment: this worked perfect

Comment: With a custom pagination design, this works fine on laravel 8. Thanks for sharing...

Comment: Worked for me as well, albeit using `$posts->links('pagination::bootstrap-5')`

Answer (score 16):

First go to the file app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php and add:

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

public function boot()
{
    
    Paginator::useBootstrap();
}
```

Use this after @endforeach in your post.blade.php:

```
{{ $blogs->links() }}
```

Comment: you just gave the same answer that @manoj did almost a year before.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use this way:

```html
$posts->links('pagination::bootstrap-4')in AppServiceProvider.php
```

Right way :

```html
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

public function boot()
{
    
    Paginator::useBootstrap();
}
```

Then in any blade, you want to use pagination like this:

```html
{{ $posts->links() }}
```